# Sqlite3 C++ database is locked

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, c++17

I want to modify the records of a row in my database, but somehow I get a `database is locked` error

```
void Bookshop::modifyBookRecords () {
    std::cout << "You want to modify a book" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Title/ISBN: ";
    std::string input;
    std::getline (std::cin, input);
    bool isAvailable = database.checkAvailability (input);
    database.closeDb ();
    if (isAvailable) {
        std::cout << "Title: ";
        std::string title;
        std::getline (std::cin, title);
        std::cout << "Author: ";
        std::string author;
        std::getline (std::cin, author);
        std::cout << "Pages: ";
        int pages;
        std::cin >> pages;
        std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max (), '\n');
        std::cout << "Genre: ";
        std::string genre;
        std::getline (std::cin, genre);
        std::cout << "Publisher: ";
        std::string publisher;
        std::getline (std::cin, publisher);
        std::cout << "ISBN: ";
        std::string isbn;
        std::getline (std::cin, isbn);
        std::cout << "Number of Copies: ";
        int numberOfCopies;
        std::cin >> numberOfCopies;
        std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max (), '\n');
        database.updateRecord (input, title, author, pages, genre, publisher, isbn, numberOfCopies);
     }
     else {
         std::cout << "The book was not found" << std::endl;
     }
}
```

CheckAvailability Method

```
bool Database::checkAvailability (std::string& input) {
    openDb (dir);
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2 (db, "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Title = ? OR Isbn = ?", -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cout << sqlite3_errmsg (db);
        closeDb ();
        return false;
    }
    sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 1, input.c_str (), input.length (), NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 2, input.c_str (), input.length (), NULL);

    if (sqlite3_step (stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        return true;
        sqlite3_finalize (stmt);
        sqlite3_close (db);
    }    
    else {
        return false;
        sqlite3_finalize (stmt);
        sqlite3_close (db);
    }
}
```

updateRecords method

```
// Method updates the whole row with the values from the parameter list
void Database::updateRecord (const std::string& input,
                         const std::string& title,
                         const std::string& author,
                         const int& pages,
                         const std::string& genre,
                         const std::string& publisher,
                         const std::string& isbn,
                         const int& numberOfCopies) {
    openDb (dir);
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2 (db, "UPDATE Books SET Title = ?, Author = ?, Pages = ?, Genre = ?, Publisher = ?, Isbn = ?, Copies = ? WHERE Title = ? OR Isbn = ?", -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg (db);
        closeDb ();
    }
    sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 1, title.c_str (), title.length (), NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 2, author.c_str (), author.length (), NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_int (stmt, 3, pages);
    sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 4, genre.c_str (), genre.length (), NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 5, publisher.c_str (), publisher.length (), NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 6, isbn.c_str (), isbn.length (), NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_int (stmt, 7, numberOfCopies);
    sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 8, input.c_str (), input.length (), NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 9, input.c_str (), input.length (), NULL);
    rc = sqlite3_step (stmt);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg (db);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "books was updated successfully" << std::endl;
    }
    sqlite3_finalize (stmt);
    closeDb ();
}
```

The error is somewhere in the checkAvailability Method, because when I remove it everything works. Someone told me, that the database is open somewhere, so it is not allowed to open it in the method later. But I closed the database at the end of checkAvailability(), so I do not know the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning from `checkAvailability` before you have closed the database. Once you return from a function, statements following the return statement are not executed. The control flow goes back to the caller of the function.

```
bool Database::checkAvailability (std::string& input) {
    openDb (dir);
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2 (db, "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Title = ? OR Isbn = ?", -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cout << sqlite3_errmsg (db);
        closeDb ();
        return false;
    }
    sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 1, input.c_str (), input.length (), NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 2, input.c_str (), input.length (), NULL);

    if (sqlite3_step (stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        sqlite3_finalize (stmt);
        sqlite3_close (db);
        return true;
    }    
    else {
        sqlite3_finalize (stmt);
        sqlite3_close (db);
        return false;
    }
}
```